# Mouse manipulation inside Virtual PC

Tags: c++, winapi, vpc

I develop an application, which automates some simple tasks inside Virtual PC. Now I faced with problem: I can't figure out how I can manipulate mouse inside VPC. I do something like this:

```
HWND hDW = (HWND)0x000B03E0; // handle to virtual machine screen    

int x = 70;
int y = 130;

SendMessage(hDW, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
SendMessage(hDW, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));

SendMessage(hDW, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, MK_RBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
SendMessage(hDW, WM_RBUTTONUP, MK_RBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone show me how perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for.

I have used the `mouse_input` to do what you are looking for but it seems that is deprecated and you should use the `SendInput` instead.

[mouse_input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260(VS.85).aspx)

[SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx)

EDIT:

you could hide the cursor during the move like this [(reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms674854(VS.85).aspx)

```
SetCrusor( GetCursor() );
ShowCursor(false);
// SendInput()  move mouse do stuff
ShowCursor(true);
```

Comment: Thanks corn3lius. SendInput works, but there is one problem with it: I need to move mouse cursor to position, where I want to perform click. How can I do it without actually moving mouse cursor?